# Dynamically load gtkmm objects with dlopen

Tags: c++, c++11, gtk, gtkmm

I have to dynamically use my library that uses Gtkmm. Unfortunately, I don't even manage to open a window in that way, and I don't understand why. Due to technical restrictions, the functions I must use are the dl* family.
Here is what I have tried so far :

My compile lines:

**for the library:**

```
g++ gtkmm.cpp -shared -fPIC -o lib.so `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs
```

for the **main**:

```
g++ main.cpp -ldl
```

file: **main.cpp**

```
#include "INibbler.hpp"
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

typedef INibbler *(*fPtr)(int x, int y);

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  void  *handle;
  fPtr  ptr;

  handle = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (handle != NULL)
    {
      ptr = reinterpret_cast<fPtr>(dlsym(handle, "returnInstance"));
      INibbler *test = reinterpret_cast<INibbler *>((*ptr)(700, 500));
      test->loopGame(ac, av);
    }
}
```

file: **gtkmm.cpp**

```
LibGtkmm::LibGtkmm(int x, int y)
{
  (void)x;
  (void)y;
  this->set_default_size(100, 100);
}

LibGtkmm::~LibGtkmm()
{

}

void LibGtkmm::loopGame(int ac, char **av)
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app
    = Gtk::Application::create(ac,av, "org.gtkmm", Gio::APPLICATION_HANDLES_OPEN);

  app->run(*this);
}

extern "C"
{
  INibbler *returnInstance(int x, int y)
  {
    std::cout << "hey" << std::endl;
    return (new LibGtkmm(x, y));
  }
}
```

file: **gtkmm.hpp**

```
#ifndef GTKMM_H_
#define GTKMM_H_

#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "../INibbler.hpp"

class   LibGtkmm : public INibbler, public Gtk::Window
{
private:
public:
  LibGtkmm(int x, int y);
  virtual ~LibGtkmm();
  virtual void loopGame(int ac, char **av);
};

#endif  // !GTKMM_H_
```

file: **INibbler.hpp**

```
#ifndef INIBBLER_HPP_
# define INIBBLER_HPP_

class   INibbler
{
public:
  virtual void  loopGame(int ac, char **av) = 0;
};

#endif /* !INIBBLER_HPP_ */
```

When I call `app->run`, the window does not open itself, and I got a lot of GTK fail messages... telling that the pointer is somehow NULL.
Here are the most notable:

```
(process:7556): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:7556): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:7556): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Does someone have an idea of how I can resolve my problem ?

Comment: "I got a lot of GTK fail messages"  Those probably contain important information, else the programmer would not have wasted his time writing them.  So share those with us, at least the first 10 or so.

Comment: Yes, of course, here are the messages:

`(process:7556): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_cascade_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed`



**appears only once**:

`(process:7556): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance`

Comment: Here they are in the question ! Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Did you forget to initialize gtkmm?

Comment: The `loopGame` function initializes the app, by running the this pointer being a `gtk::window`

Comment: You have to call the `Gtk::Application` stuff before calling any other GTK+ function. By making `LibGtkmm` derive from `Gtk::Window`, creating a new `LibGtkmm` causes the `Gtk::Window` initialization functions (including your `set_default_size()` call) to be run before the `Gtk::Application` stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem: You don't have a Gtk::Main.

Solution: Create a Gtk::Main. You need this:

```
Gtk::Main main(argc, argv);
main.run();
```

To avoid Gtkmm freaking out, create the Gtk::Main as soon as possible. Call main.run() once you've initialized everything.